# Can't use middleware in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to put together a little ASP.NET Core app, following Scott Allen's [Pluralsight course](https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/aspdotnet-core-1-0-fundamentals). 
I'm on macOS.

my `project.json` dependencies look like this:

```
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "type": "platform",
          "version": "1.0.0"
        },
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
```

And I Restored all necessary packages.

My `Startup.cs` looks like this:

```
...
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
 {
      app.UseFileServer(); // 'IApplicationBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'UseFileServer' and no extension method 'UseFileServer' accepting a first argument of type 'IApplicationBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [netcoreapp1.0]
      app.Run(context =>
      {
          return context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello from ASP.NET Core!");
       });
  }
...
```

I seem to have all dependencies in place, but compiler complaints about not seeing extension method for any middleware (`UseFileServer` for example)

Any ideas?

Comment: You're mixing rc1 and RTM packages. You should use 1.0.0 packages everywhere. Also use 'AspNetCore' packages.

Comment: @HenkMollema, yeah I seem to be mixing `AspNet` and `AspNetCore` libraries, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `"Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" : "1.0.0"` dependency to your project.json file, or follow the suggestions of the IDE when you click `Ctrl+.` on the error (dunno if it works in Visual Studio Code though).

Also you may have to include `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder` namespace, since that's where `UseFileServer` resides in within the static files library